# Is this Intel Hex firmware file corrupted?

Tags: microcontroller, intel, disassembly, firmware

I have a firmware file with [Intel Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) format which belongs to a [P80C528EBA microcontroller](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/364/P80C528EBA_02.php). This microcontroller is an 8-Bit mC and it is based on 80C51 architecture.

Below, you can see the first 5 lines of the file:

```
     :llaaaattddddddcc
   1 :03800000028100FA
   2 :028003008028D3
   3 :02800B00806093
   4 :0280130080608B
   5 :01801B003232
```

As you may know and I have added in the above, Intel Hex format lines have structure as below:

```
:llaaaattddddd..............cc
|||||||||||                 CC->Checksum
|||||||||DD->Data...
|||||||TT->Record Type
|||AAAA->Address
|LL->Record Length
:->Colon
```

As you see above in the first 5 line of my file, the `AAAA` value of the line #2 is `0x8003` and it is equal to `LL` + `AAAA` of line #1 (0x03 + 0x8000). But this pattern is not correct for the next 3 lines. For example for the line #3 we expect 0x8005 which is equal to 0x8003 + 0x02 (`AAAA` + `LL` Of line #2), but surprisingly we have 0x800B. I have about 10 lines with wrong patterns in this file (which have about 2000 lines).

**Question: Does that mean that the file is corrupted and some lines are deleted? Or it is OK to have some hollows between lines (as above) in the Intel Hex format?**

Comment: what does the tool show before the conversion to hex?  what file format options do you have.  it is likely that the rest of the data is assumed to be zeros or all ones.

Comment: please show a minimal complete example, minimal source code, what tools used to generate some output then the tool(s) used to convert that to a hex file.  What you saw when you compared the intermediate files to the hex file, etc.  or perhaps what tool consumes this hex file, etc...

Comment: the intel hex format is not relevant here, it is just a way to represent the data relative to addresses, it is the tools that generate it and tools that consume it for the use case that matter. "intel hex file format" is just a way to represent addresses and data it has no larger rules as to what you can represent with it or how, the format does not govern what happens outside or between lines (with the exception of how the address can be extended but that is not relevant here).

Comment: A quick inspection with any number of readers that can interpret HEX format would have told you the file is internally consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files is not corrupted, all checksums are correct.

The only thing I would expect is the end-of-file record

```
:00000001FF
```

But as you say, the file is much longer than the extract you show.

Anyway, it is completely OK for an [Intelhex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) file to have gaps.

Additionally, the records don't have to be in order.

If you disassemble the machine code, you get

```
C8000:  ljmp    C8100
C8003:  sjmp    C802D
C800B:  sjmp    C806D
C8013:  sjmp    C8075
C801B:  reti
```

You are looking at the locations where reset and interrupt routines start.

Comment: Great! Thankyou. would you please tell me which tool did you used to disassemble it? I want to disassemble whole the file.

Comment: This is a table-driven disassembler I wrote many years ago. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I have both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Anyway, what's the point of having multiple consecutive sjmp, ljmp jump instructions in the begining of the firmware?

Comment: Since I miss the time to find a new provider for my homepage for some years now, there are just some mirrors left, [for example this one](http://bodo4all.fortunecity.ws/misc/disasm.html). The code is bad and old, it might need some massage before it can be compiled nowadays. -- Anyway, Ghidra looks as if it should be able to disassemble, but I never tried it.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try it. thank you. I tried Ghidra, but it seems that there are some issues. I posted another question about Ghidra: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65461103/how-to-disassemble-80c51-firmware

Comment: About the locations: Please read the documentation of the microcontroller, or the 8051 in general. This issue is beyond SO and this question. However, in short, at reset and on interrupts the processor core jumps to (reset) or calls (interrupt) these specific locations. Programmers tend to put jumps there, because the whole ISR might not fit in the space before the next used location. -- You might like to visit the wikipedia page of the MCS51 to get some links to documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226489/discussion-between-the-busybee-and-abraham).